# I have 100 MB .XLSX File(Multitab) uploaded to Google drive while extracting getting Error Exceeding file size

Tags: javascript, sourceforge-appscript

I'm currently creating a script that can import xlsx file stored from gdrive folder to spreadsheet, But my file size is over 50 MB so i am getting error " Exceeding file size". the excel file contain with multiple sheet. So please help me to find the possible way to convert large file to spreadsheet.

Below code i have which is working fine for below 50 MB file size.

```
var filename = excelFile

Logger.log(filename)
  var fileId = excelFile.getId();
  var folderId = Drive.Files.get(fileId).parents[0].id;
  var blob = excelFile.getBlob();


  var resource = {
  title: excelFile.getName(),
  mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  parents: [{id: folderId}],
  };

  var sourceSpreadsheet = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheet.id);
```